# How to remove duplicate source list on Debian 8.7

Tags: debian, duplicate, resources

Am running Debian 8.7, after installing #letsencrypt following the tutorial on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-debian-8). I couldn't update my operating system any more, If I run `sudo apt-get update` it displays the following error at the end

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry ...ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems</code>
```

In other to view my source lists, I run the following code `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

which diplays the following result

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-jessie main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-compute-jessie main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-jessie main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-jessie main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-compute-jessie main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-jessie main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Please, guys, which resource should I remove and how what code or process should I take to remove it.
I don't know much about these whole thing, I just follows instructions found on net to do all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicated source list is `...ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main.`. You need to remove it. Do a `grep jessie-backports /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and `grep jessie-backports /etc/apt/sources.list`, see which files have it, open it with a text editor (e.g. nano), remove it and then do `apt-get update` to refresh apt's cache.

Comment: Thank you very much. You idea works well! I used it to find the main culprit and the use @SYN solution to solve it in one click.

Answer (score 0):

According to the DigitalOcean doc you're referring to, my money's on:

```
rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
apt-get update
```

As you can see, there's two `jessie-backports` in you `cat` output, ...

Comment: That's great. I used @Jeff-Schaller idea to find the culprit, though you stated it here, then use the code you gave to remove it in one click.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run python in your system. You can use the following python3 script to make a copy of the file with no duplicates. After which you can replace the older "sources.list" with the new file

```
import os

l = set()
# remove duplicates by adding all the lines to a set
with open("/etc/apt/sources.list") as f:
    for line in f:
        l.add(line)
# write the new lines to a file in your home folder
with open("/home/brianbrix/sources.list", "w") as f:
    for line in l:
        f.write(line)
        f.write("\n")

# after that you can replace the sources file wwith the new one which has no duplicates
```